# How to find item added and click on the Item in tree-view to edit the specific item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I want to click on the Item I have previously added in the tree-view.  I cannot right click on the item to get element but got it to click on a different place close to the tree-view. This is what I get from Inspect element:

```html
<div id="OrganizationUnitEditTree" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default" role="tree" tabindex="0"
     aria-activedescendant="2a0e05fc-f2d8-6016-90d7-39f733854e8d" aria-busy="false">
    <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children jstree-contextmenu jstree-wholerow-ul jstree-no-dots" role="group">
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="1a441850-3b8a-97f0-d729-39f769eecf68_anchor" id="1a441850-3b8a-97f0-d729-39f769eecf68"
            class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="1a441850-3b8a-97f0-d729-39f769eecf68_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00009"
                                                                                   class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                   data-ou-id="1a441850-3b8a-97f0-d729-39f769eecf68">A_Test_NewOrganisation3 <i
                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a></li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="9c9d67dc-5a12-670d-2c83-39f765d3869a_anchor" id="9c9d67dc-5a12-670d-2c83-39f765d3869a"
            class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="9c9d67dc-5a12-670d-2c83-39f765d3869a_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00008"
                                                                                   class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                   data-ou-id="9c9d67dc-5a12-670d-2c83-39f765d3869a">A_Test_NewOrganisaton2 <i
                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a></li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="6f099933-c64f-b70f-2d0b-39f73384a611_anchor" aria-expanded="true"
            id="6f099933-c64f-b70f-2d0b-39f73384a611" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="6f099933-c64f-b70f-2d0b-39f73384a611_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00001"
                                                                                   class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                   data-ou-id="6f099933-c64f-b70f-2d0b-39f73384a611">DDB <i
                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a>
            <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
                <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2"
                    aria-labelledby="f3568485-ca3d-843e-c7c9-39f733851fc0_anchor"
                    id="f3568485-ca3d-843e-c7c9-39f733851fc0" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                    <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"
                                                                                 tabindex="-1"
                                                                                 id="f3568485-ca3d-843e-c7c9-39f733851fc0_anchor"><i
                        class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00001.00001"
                                                                                           class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                           data-ou-id="f3568485-ca3d-843e-c7c9-39f733851fc0">Server <i
                        class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="2ed9aa04-644b-9f8f-5519-39f73c907314_anchor" id="2ed9aa04-644b-9f8f-5519-39f73c907314"
            class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="2ed9aa04-644b-9f8f-5519-39f73c907314_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00006"
                                                                                   class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                   data-ou-id="2ed9aa04-644b-9f8f-5519-39f73c907314">Test000001 <i
                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a></li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="2a0e05fc-f2d8-6016-90d7-39f733854e8d_anchor" id="2a0e05fc-f2d8-6016-90d7-39f733854e8d"
            class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="2a0e05fc-f2d8-6016-90d7-39f733854e8d_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00002"
                                                                                   class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                   data-ou-id="2a0e05fc-f2d8-6016-90d7-39f733854e8d">Test3 <i
                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a></li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="e61e6d4a-48c9-9482-3038-39f73c8ac402_anchor" aria-expanded="true"
            id="e61e6d4a-48c9-9482-3038-39f73c8ac402" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="e61e6d4a-48c9-9482-3038-39f73c8ac402_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00005"
                                                                                   class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                   data-ou-id="e61e6d4a-48c9-9482-3038-39f73c8ac402">Test_Anneline900 <i
                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a>
            <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
                <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2"
                    aria-labelledby="4aba2729-3645-4945-7e0e-39f7462c78de_anchor" aria-expanded="true"
                    id="4aba2729-3645-4945-7e0e-39f7462c78de" class="jstree-node  jstree-open jstree-last">
                    <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"
                                                                                 tabindex="-1"
                                                                                 id="4aba2729-3645-4945-7e0e-39f7462c78de_anchor"><i
                        class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00005.00001"
                                                                                           class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                                                                           data-ou-id="4aba2729-3645-4945-7e0e-39f7462c78de">Test_Anneline900_SubUnit <i
                        class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a>
                    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
                        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="3"
                            aria-labelledby="6be059ba-3756-fc08-faca-39f7468aa122_anchor"
                            id="6be059ba-3756-fc08-faca-39f7468aa122" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
                            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"
                                                                                         tabindex="-1"
                                                                                         id="6be059ba-3756-fc08-faca-39f7468aa122_anchor"><i
                                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span
                                title="00005.00001.00001" class="ou-text text-dark ou-text-no-members"
                                data-ou-id="6be059ba-3756-fc08-faca-39f7468aa122">Test_Anneline900_SubUnit <i
                                class="fa fa-caret-down text-muted"></i> </span> </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1"
            aria-labelledby="8de880f3-846f-801e-8e57-39f743122249_anchor" id="8de880f3-846f-801e-8e57-39f743122249"
            class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1"
                                                                         id="8de880f3-846f-801e-8e57-39f743122249_anchor"><i
                class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span title="00007">
```

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CreateNewSubUnitOrganisationUnits
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CreateNewSubUnit
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\");

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://Website/");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        }

        [TestCase]
        public void Test1()
        {
            //Enter the Login details
            IWebElement UserName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginInput_UserNameOrEmailAddress"));
            UserName.SendKeys("admin");
            IWebElement PassWord = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginInput_Password"));
            PassWord.SendKeys("1q2w3E*");
            IWebElement LoginButton2 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.d-flex.align-items-center > div > div > div > div.card > div.card-body > div > form > button"));
            LoginButton2.Click();

            //Click on Administration
            IWebElement AdminiStration = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mCSB_1_container']/nav/ul/li[3]/a/span[2]"));
            AdminiStration.Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            //Click on Identity Managment Link
            IWebElement IdManageLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/nav/ul/li[3]/ul/li[2]/a/span[2]"));
            IdManageLink.Click();

            //Click on Organisation Unit
            IWebElement OrgUnit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/nav/ul/li[3]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]"));
            OrgUnit.Click();


//This is where I want to search for the item added in the Tree-view:
            //Click on the Organisation Unit added
            Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
            action2.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).Build().Perform();
            IWebElement ClickOnOrganisation = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span"));
            ClickOnOrganisation.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below code

```
Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
action2.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).Build().Perform();
IWebElement ClickOnOrganisation = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span"));
ClickOnOrganisation.Click();
```

to

```
Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
action2.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).click().Build().Perform();
```

In other words, do `click()` by `action2`.

In addition, it is NOT recommended to use absolute Xpath.

Comment: Hi, @Anneline , if this is the solution to your problem, please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :)